# Call library movieclips from an array of strings

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an array of strings. Each string is a name of a class. How can I call the library item with the class name that corresponds to the string in the array?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `getDefinitionByName`, found in the package flash.utils.

Usually the code will look something like this:

```
var oClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("<name of your class>") as Class;
var instance:Object = new oClass();
```

You can also cast `instance` to a type of your choice:

```
var myType:SomeType = SomeType(instance);
```

See this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29) for reference.